# Error 'openssl/crypto.h' file not found when installing PycURL on Mac using pip

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pip, openssl, pycurl

When installing Python3 packages on macOS X 10.15 Catalina using `pip install -r requirements.txt` I am getting this error:

```
× Running setup.py install for pycurl did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [25 lines of output]
      /private/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/pip-install-8r44qz4e/pycurl_09ab3d56141443439eb3f41fa62f7b0f/setup.py:771: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
        if LooseVersion(distutils.__version__) > LooseVersion("1.0.1"):
      /private/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/pip-install-8r44qz4e/pycurl_09ab3d56141443439eb3f41fa62f7b0f/setup.py:773: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
        if LooseVersion(distutils.__version__) < LooseVersion("1.0.3"):
      Using curl-config (libcurl 7.84.0)
      running install
      /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-cpython-39
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-cpython-39/curl
      copying python/curl/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-cpython-39/curl
      running build_ext
      building 'pycurl' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-cpython-39
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-cpython-39/src
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -DPYCURL_VERSION=\"7.43.0\" -DHAVE_CURL_OPENSSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.84.0/include -I/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c src/docstrings.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-cpython-39/src/docstrings.o
      In file included from src/docstrings.c:4:
      src/pycurl.h:170:13: fatal error: 'openssl/crypto.h' file not found
      #   include <openssl/crypto.h>
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
```

So It fails on installing PycURL because it cannot find the `openssl` include directory.

I have first added `cryptography==37.0.4` to the `requirements.txt` file but then I got:

```
src/pycurl.h:178:13: fatal error: 'openssl/ssl.h' file not found
```

Then I have tried installing latest `openssl` with:

```
brew update
brew install openssl
brew link --force openssl
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.3.dylib /usr/local/lib/
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.3.dylib /usr/local/lib/
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/3.0.4/bin/openssl /usr/local/bin/openssl
```

But it didn't help.

I also tried:

```
export PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=openssl
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/include"

pip install --no-cache-dir --compile --ignore-installed --install-option="--with-openssl" pycurl
```

But also with no success.
Any help on this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What eventually helped was:

1. Remove `pycurl` from the `requirements.txt` file
2. Install `openssl` with: `brew install openssl`
3. Find `openssl` installation directory with

```
$ brew --prefix openssl
/usr/local/opt/openssl@3

$ ls -la /usr/local/opt/openssl@3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 runner  admin  25 Jul  6 09:13 /usr/local/opt/openssl@3 -> ../Cellar/openssl@3/3.0.4
```

4. Install PycURL specifying inline the above `openssl` install directories like this:

```
PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=openssl LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@3/3.0.4/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@3/3.0.4/include" pip3 install --no-cache-dir pycurl
```

5. Now the PycURL installs without any problem:

```
Collecting pycurl
  Downloading pycurl-7.45.1.tar.gz (233 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 233.9/233.9 kB 64.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Building wheels for collected packages: pycurl
  Building wheel for pycurl (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for pycurl (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for pycurl: filename=pycurl-7.45.1-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_15_x86_64.whl size=146607 sha256=aff9581cbd6ddec739c529df376ad2d4edf49dafdad179a9b68bddeb60a739b3
  Stored in directory: /private/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-hjqadgim/wheels/4d/ef/77/ffab9dc4b0016ce4f780b752e0020815e416f0d27a701a816f
Successfully built pycurl
Installing collected packages: pycurl
Successfully installed pycurl-7.45.1
```

Comment: It helped to install the pycurl, but still not able to import pycurl?

Comment: It usually happens when you install `pycurl` on the system level and then trying using it within a virtual environment (`venv`) which uses a different Python version. So, for example, your system Python can be 2.x while your `venv` may use Python 3.x. Always create a `venv` for your project.  Then after installing everything (requirements.txt + pycurl) inside you `venv` you should test your installation

Comment: You can test your installation in Terminal by executing `which python`, then executing `<your-python-path> -m pip list`. If the installation was successful you should see `pycurl` on the list, then execute `<your-python-path`. Now, being in Python, try to execute `import pycurl`. It should work. Then exit Python with `exit()`. If you are using VS Code make sure you select the right interpreter from your `venv`. You should see the Python interpreter version at the bottom right in your IDE. Or else do `CMD+SHIFT+P` then `>Python: Select Interpreter`.

Comment: I always use VENV for my projects.  I followed your steps to test the installation and tried to import the python, getting this error `ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time version (7.77.0) is older than compile-time version (7.79.1)`
couldn't resolve this error yet. how can I resolve this?

Comment: If you are using Python > 3.7.x then try switching to Python 3.7.x

Comment: I updated my python version to 3.8.10, still pycurl is giving hard time to get installed

Comment: I said to try Python 3.7.x

Comment: I cant try Python 3.7.x, its a project dependency.

Comment: This worked like magic. Mac OS 13 Ventura, Django 4.1.9, Celery 5.1.3, M2 Apple Silicon Chip

Answer (score 1):

Using `brew --prefix openssl` to dynamically lookup the paths for LDFLAGS, CPPFLAGS, and PKG_CONFIG_PATH:

```bash
OPENSSL_DIR=$(brew --prefix openssl) \
LDFLAGS="-L${OPENSSL_DIR}/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I${OPENSSL_DIR}/include" \
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="${OPENSSL_DIR}/lib/pkgconfig" \
pip install pycurl
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

first install openssl

```
brew install openssl
```

then

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/lib/pkgconfig"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/include"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/lib"
```

the exception go away

```
pip3 install pycurl
DEPRECATION: Configuring installation scheme with distutils config files is deprecated and will no longer work in the near future. If you are using a Homebrew or Linuxbrew Python, please see discussion at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/76621
Collecting pycurl
  Using cached pycurl-7.45.2.tar.gz (234 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pycurl
  Building wheel for pycurl (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for pycurl: filename=pycurl-7.45.2-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_13_x86_64.whl size=144557 sha256=2c56c17f7987b8739333b8078c6d8b61ed5c8e5239ea182992bbe0eb64208970
  Stored in directory: /Users/xlla/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/23/b0/37/d2c3211ee738adfb8ec6b6e10aa00e78ebc4de363f862a12c5
Successfully built pycurl
Installing collected packages: pycurl
Successfully installed pycurl-7.45.2
```